# nativescript: error when publishing via Local Build

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-sidekick

I can do cloud builds successfully but I am having issues with Local Builds.  I checked xCod under Signings & Capabilities and the provisioning profile is setup properly but when publishing a Local Build in Nativescript Sidekick, I keep getting this error in the Sidekick console:

```
Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""mathLearn.app" requires a provisioning 
profile." UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription="mathLearn.app" 
requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the 
"provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}
```

Not sure how to resolve this since the provisioning profile is setup in xcode properly AND the cert/provisioning profile were selected in Sidekick when initiating the publish.

Comment: I'm not much of Sidekick user, did you try using tns build command?

Comment: @manoj I just tried using the command line `tns publish ios` with my creds.  I get same: `Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""musueminsider.app" requires a provisioning profile." UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription="musueminsider.app" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}

** EXPORT FAILED **

Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 70`

Comment: Did you create mobile provision on developer portal?

Comment: @Manoj yes, I have an ios Distribution cert and a distribution provision profile.  I used those 2 to make numerous cloud builds and upload them to the Appstore Connect so I know they are working.  I am having issues with the Cloud upload caching data, even with "Clean" build enabled so that's why I'm trying to do local builds now but having this issue

Comment: Try passing the provisional profile id in `--provision` param.

Comment: workerd!  thanks for all your help today.  Want to create an answer with that so I can select it as the answer in case it will help out anyone else who looks up the same question?

Comment: @HoraceLata How did it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may pass the provisional profile as an argument.

```
tns publish ios ... --provision <Your Mobile Provisioning Profile Identifier>
```

Read more at [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/publishing/publish-ios)

Comment: I have a similar issue in Jenkins. How do I resolve there? Any known solution?